# How to create a logical paper and pencil game like Sudoku?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sudoku

This question is not limited to Sudoku, but may include Kakuro, Hitori, Nurikabe, etc.

I understand the algorithm to **solve** Sudoku and other similar puzzles, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to **create** them.

Say I want a Sudoku generator (to take the most popular). I guess it needs to work in two steps:

1. Create a valid solution
2. Remove parts of the solution until the desired amount of clues are left.

Creating a solution isn't trivial, it usually works well if you go randomly until you reach the last steps and end up in a deadlock.

Removing some parts of the solution required to be sure to remove only redundant ones, which isn't trivial either.

Is there a generic algorithm to work it out? How can I implement such a thing?

I understand my question is "broad" and that I don't show a lot of what I've got so far (splitting the problem in two), but I don't have any lead to start thinking about the algorithm. I'm not asking for a solution, but rather for hints on how to begin.

Comment: I have a feeling that my question could be on the wrong site of the StackExchange, please let me know if you have a better place to put it.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com

Comment: To be a valid Sudoku, the solution must also be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could in general approach this as follows:

Define a set of rules which can assist a human in progressing in a game. For instance, in Sudoku, one of those rules could be:

- Call the "field of influence" of a given cell, the cells that are either in the same row, the same column or in the same 3x3 block as that given cell. The rule is that this cell cannot have any of the values that are already used in its field of influence. If that means there is only one valid value left, then place that value in this cell.

Another rule could be:

- If there is a value that cannot be used anywhere else in the same 3x3 block, then place that value in this cell. Similarly if a value cannot be used anywhere else in the cell's row; or cannot be used anywhere else in the cell's column.

There are obviously other rules. These rules can be more complicated. Rank the rules by how difficult it is for a human to verify and apply them. Try to be as complete as you can, by looking how you, as a human, reason when solving the game. Implement these rules as functions in the program. In the Sudoku example, such a rule function can be applied to a given cell, and return success (i.e. the cell gets a value) or failure (the rule cannot be used to deduct its value).

Let's say the program should generate a Sudoku of a given difficulty. We will interpret that to mean that solving the Sudoku will require the player to use at least once a rule that has at least that difficulty, or an exotic rule that was never foreseen.

Now start from a solved Sudoku. Remove randomly 50% of the values. Check if the Sudoku can be solved by only using known rules that are within the difficulty range. If not, restore 25% of the removed cells, and repeat. If it could be solved, remove 25% more cells randomly. Continue halving the number of involved cells (either restoring them or removing them), much like a binary search algorithm, until you arrive at the end of this search. For a Sudoku game, this process would take about 7 iterations. Then you will have a kind of "local minimum", where the rules can be applied to get to a solution.

This is far from perfect, as it could well be there is some other cell that could be cleared, while still allowing the rules to work towards a solution. So, if you want to refine this search, you could add some additional iterations to remove random cells as long as the resulting board can still be solved by applying the rules.

Comment: Clear and precise. Thank you! Is it something you have done before or are you creating the technic on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Sudoku puzzle by solving one that starts with nothing assigned to start with.  If your solver progresses by filling in squares, you could "remove" them by stopping (or rolling back) that process at the appropriate point.